# Why does the error "No name 'search' in module 'googlesearch'" come up in Python?

Tags: python, python-import, importerror, google-search

Recently, the googlesearch function for python worked fine for me. I could search things up (to a degree. Still working out some kinks) and I would have no error. Recently though, I've been getting the error message `No name 'search' in module 'googlesearch'` for some reason.

The import I'm doing is `from googlesearch import search`. I've tried `from googlesearch.googlesearch import GoogleSearch` as well. I can't get anything to run because I cannot find a suitable site that will help me with the error message, nor any documentation that has any functions on it. Does anyone have a solution to the error?

Comment: Is your script named `googlesearch.py`, or is there a file with this name in the same directory that you're running your script from?  If so, try renaming it to something else.

Comment: It has a different name. The browse function I'm adding is just a part of the project. Nothing about googlesearch.py except in the import.